# Laravel 4 Multiple Bindings to A View

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

What is the best way to bind multiple results to a view? The following does not work but it captures my logic:

```
   public function show($id)
{
    $nests = Nest::with('user')->find($id);
    $notes = Note::with('nest')->where('nest_id', '=', $id);
    return View::make('nests.show', compact('nests', 'notes'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do it:

`return View::make('nests.show',array('nests'=>$nests,'notes'=>$notes));`

Comment: This is exactly what the compact function does

Comment: Just tested this with a controller of mine using the `compact()` function and both variables came through to the view. @user2038291 perhaps try `composer update` to make sure you are on the latest version of Laravel 4?

Answer (score 0):

I used this code

```
return View::make('myviewfolder.myview', compact('view1','view2','viewN'));
```

I am using PHP 5.5

Here is the info on the compact function

[PHP Compact Function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php)